# Swift - sortTable shall update view immediately

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift, hence I'm open for any suggestion related to my code, since I have concerns about the efficiency of the app.

My intention is to update the view, everytime a action is called. - I've got a TableView inside of my ViewController and I want the user to be able to sort the table asc or desc on click.

Theoretically the code works and the user is able to click the given button which changes `isAsc`. But I haven't been able to update the view instantly after the button was clicked. So far, it only updates when I leave the ViewController and come back from another by `preformSegue`.

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var isAsc = true

    var gefahreneKm: [String] = []
    var date: [String] = []
    var consumedLiters: [String] = []
    var pricePerLiter: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        isAsc = defaults.bool(forKey: "isAsc")
        gefahreneKm = createArray()
        date = createArrayDate()
        consumedLiters = createArrayConsumedL()
        pricePerLiter = createArrayPricePerLitre()
        self.toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),
                                        forToolbarPosition: .any,
                                        barMetrics: .default)
        self.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)
        timlineView.delegate = self
        timlineView.dataSource = self 
    }

    func createArray() -> [String] {
        let arrayDrivenKmString = arrayDrivenKm.map{ String($0) }

        if isAsc == true {
            return arrayDrivenKmString
        } else {
            return arrayDrivenKmString.reversed()
        }
    }

    func createArrayDate() -> [String] {
        if isAsc == true {
            return arrayDate
        } else {
            return arrayDate.reversed()
        }
    }

    func createArrayConsumedL() -> [String] {
        if isAsc == true {
            return arrayConsumedL
        } else {
            return arrayConsumedL.reversed()
        }
    }

    func createArrayPricePerLitre() -> [String] {
        if isAsc == true {
            return arrayPricePerLiter
        } else {
            return arrayPricePerLiter.reversed()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonBack(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goBackToMain", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func sortTable(_ sender: Any) {
        isAsc = !isAsc
        defaults.set(isAsc, forKey: "isAsc")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recreate data that needs to be changed after the sort and reload table to see the changes.

```
func createData() {
  gefahreneKm = createArray()
  date = createArrayDate()
  consumedLiters = createArrayConsumedL()
  pricePerLiter = createArrayPricePerLitre()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   isAsc = defaults.bool(forKey: "isAsc")
   createData()
   // Rest of the code
} 

@IBAction func sortTable(_ sender: Any) {
   isAsc = !isAsc
   defaults.set(isAsc, forKey: "isAsc")
   createData()
   timlineView.reloadData()
}
```

Couple of recommendations:

- rename functions from create* to get* as they are not creating any data.
- create struct to manage your data model.

Comment: @rmaddy It's working, thank you both! I put the declaration of the arrays inside of an extra function which is now being called in both `viewDidLoad()`& `sortTable()`.